# Dynamic collection of signatures

Tags: multi-sig

I'm wondering how Stellar solves the issue of the collection of signatures for an transaction requiring multiple signatures **or** an account operation that requires multiple signers.

For example, assume a transaction involves parties `A`, `B`, and `C` and requires their signatures. How can the transaction proposal be propagate from the initiator to the other parties for signing?

In other words, besides the `Offer` operation, which automatically finds corresponding offers for you. How can a *proposal* for a transaction that requires multiple signatures be sent to other parties? What about account operations with a multi-sig threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it’s done completely off network - you need a way to share the transaction with the other parties and collect signatures. Several wallets and products do their own multisig coordination, and others are working on more generalized solutions right now.